# How to select rows that have more than 1 distinct values in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have 4 tables:

**[PERSON]

```
ID_Person   Person_NAME**
    1   First name 1 Last name 1
    2   First name 2 Last name 2
    3   First name 3 Last name 3
    4   First name 4 Last name 4
    5   First name 5 Last name 5
    6   First name 6 Last name 6

**[mobile_number]
ID  Mobile_Number   OPERATOR**
1   797900010   M
2   797900011   M
3   698900010   I
4   797900012   I
5   698900011   J
6   797900013   T
7   797900011   J
8   698900012   I
9   797900014   L
10  698900013   M
11  797900015   M


**[user_mobile]
ID  ID_USER ID_MOBILE**
1   1   1
2   1   3
3   1   11
4   2   6
5   2   8
6   3   5
7   3   10
8   4   2
9   5   4
10  5   7
11  6   9

**[MESSAGE_ID]
ID_Message  ID_MOBILE   Message Date**
1   1   text 1          12/04/2011
2   1   text 2          07/07/2011
3   1   text 3          05/11/2011
4   2   text 4          01/13/2012
5   2   text 5          17/02/2012
6   2   text 6          13/12/2012
7   3   text 7          25/12/2011
8   4   text 8          11/11/2012
9   4   text 9          03/03/2012
10  5   text 10         30/04/2012
11  5   text 11         28/02/2012
12  6   text 12         01/06/2011
13  7   text 13         19/08/2010
14  8   text 14         22/12/2010
15  8   text 15         14/05/2010
16  9   text 16         09/04/2012
17  10  text 17         11/05/2011
18  11  text 18         15/01/2012
```

**I have to select all users that have sent sms in different years
Columns to be displayed: Person Name, Mobile Number, SMSText, Year**

**My solution:**

```
    Select a.Person_Name, Mobile_Nr, message, year(Date) as Years from PERSON a
    inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
    inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
    inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
    group by Person_Name, Mobile_Nr,message,year(Date)
    having count(distinct year(date))>1
```

But it does not return nothing. if i change it to "`having count(distinct year(date))=1`" i get :

```
     **Person_Name  Mobile_Nr     message   Years**
Firstname 1 Lastname 1  698900010   text7   2011
Firstname 1 Lastname 1  797900010   text1   2011
Firstname 1 Lastname 1  797900010   text2   2011
Firstname 1 Lastname 1  797900010   text3   2011
Firstname 1 Lastname 1  797900015   text18  2012
Firstname 2 Lastname 2  698900012   text14  2010
Firstname 2 Lastname 2  698900012   text15  2010
Firstname 2 Lastname 2  797900013   text12  2011
Firstname 3 Lastname 3  698900011   text10  2012
Firstname 3 Lastname 3  698900011   text11  2012
Firstname 3 Lastname 3  698900013   text17  2011
Firstname 4 Lastname 4  797900011   text4   2012
Firstname 4 Lastname 4  797900011   text5   2012
Firstname 4 Lastname 4  797900011   text6   2012
Firstname 5 Lastname 5  698900009   text13  2010
Firstname 5 Lastname 5  797900012   text8   2012
Firstname 5 Lastname 5  797900012   text9   2012
Firstname 6 Lastname 6  797900014   text16  2012
```

**But this is wrong, i want to display only the users that sent sms in different years.**

Comment: You are trying to have your cake and eat it too.  If you only want to display the users, don't display the phone numbers or messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -- same base query, plus a WHERE-clause subquery that filters out Persons who did not have calls from multiple years.

```
--  Person, phone number, message, and year, for persons who had messages in multiple years
Select a.Person_Name, Mobile_Nr, message, year(Date) as Years
 from PERSON a
 inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
 inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
 inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
 where a.ID_PERSON in (select a.ID_PERSON
                        from PERSON a
                         inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
                         inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
                         inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
                        group by a.ID_PERSON
                        having count(distinct year(d.date)) > 1)
```

(I couldn't check the syntax, but the concept is sound)

Comment: When using Stack Overflow, if answers are helpful, you should upvote them, and (as the question asker) eventually select what you consider the "best" answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Select a.Person_Name, Mobile_Nr, message, year(D.Date) as Years from PERSON a
    inner join USER_MOBILE b on a.ID_PERSON=b.ID_USER
    inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c on b.ID_MOBILE=C.ID
    inner join MESSAGE_ID d on c.ID=d.ID_Mobile
WHERE 

EXISTS(

    SELECT 1 
    FROM 
       PERSON a1
       INNER JOIN USER_MOBILE b1 on a1.ID_PERSON=b1.ID_USER
       inner join MOBILE_NUMBER c1 on b1.ID_MOBILE=C1.ID
       inner join MESSAGE_ID d1 on c1.ID=d1.ID_Mobile
    WHERE 
       C1.MOBILE_NUMBER = C.MOBILE_NUMBER AND 
       year(D1.Date)<>year(D.DATE) 

)
```

I know it could be simplified a lot, but I just wanted to demonstrate the concept here

Comment: I get the same result as in my last code block, i get all users that sent sms regardless the years.

Comment: I misunderstood your requirements. I updated the answer, try it now.

Comment: If we look at your sample data set, there are no two messages that has been sent from the same number in different years. Are you sure that 0 rows is not correct answer here?

Comment: Also, I found that `mobile_number` is not unique in `MOBILE_NUMBER` table. Updated the query so it tolerates with that.

Comment: I am looking for messages sent in different years, not for the same messages sent in 1 year.
So an example of what i need is:
User    Message   year

1       text1    2010
1       text2    2011
1       text3    2011

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is quite close.  The problem is that you are aggregating by `year(date)`, so only one year can appear on any given row.  Try this:

```
   Select a.Person_Name, Mobile_Nr, message,
          count(distinct year(Date)) as Years
   from PERSON a inner join
        USER_MOBILE b
        on a.ID_PERSON = b.ID_USER inner join
        MOBILE_NUMBER c
        on b.ID_MOBILE = C.ID inner join
        MESSAGE_ID d
        on c.ID = d.ID_Mobile
    group by Person_Name, Mobile_Nr, message
    having count(distinct year(date)) > 1;
```

Comment: I initially thought so, but you are grouping also by message text, so the result will be wrong as you will find users who have two exactly equal messages in the same year

Comment: I get the same result as in my last code block, i get all users that sent sms regardless the years.

Comment: @KasparsOzols . . . `count(distinct)` requires that there be more than one year.  This should only be returning users who sent the same message in multiple years.

Comment: Exactly, but group is made taking into account message text and this is wrong. You will find distinct user + message text combinations sent in two different years.